# Help in making form builder using Yii

Tags: php, yii

Hey Friends I want to make a form builder using Yii.

For that I made the database table as:

```
[user]-> user_id
[form]-> id, user_id
[form_elements]-> form_id
[form_values]-> id, form_id
[table]-> id, form_id, form_elements_id, form_values_id, user_id
```

I made the model class for the database tables for making them accessible. So for making the form_builder do i need to make them CRUD or make them form generator through Gii tools?

Please help me as I am new to Yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I grasp your schema correctly, you're about to make a layer on top of [CForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm). Your application will presumably have two interfaces:

- one that is generating forms based on the data in your database, and accepting end-user inputs,
- and another that will manipulate the form fields.

For the first, you need to develop a special library to interpret your data into CForm configuration and store the input in a separate database (and by separate I mean a database that is not covered in your specs above).

For the second, yes, you will need a CRUD application (as a start at least) to deal with those objects in a convenient way.

Comment: thanks pestaa for your reply.Can You tell me for which page I have to make CRUD.I think for the final table page?where all the id values are present?

Comment: CRUD is made for each table you want to manipulate through an interface. If you haven't done the tutorial, I highly recommend it as it helps to understand how each components fits in the big picture.